# How can we hide a column in an one2many tree view?

Tags: xml, one-to-many, odoo-8, odoo

Does someone know how we can hide a column in an one2many tree view ?

**XML snippet**:

```xml
 <field name="bom_line_ids" widget="one2many_list">
     <tree string="Components" editable="bottom" > 
        <field name="sequence"    widget="handle"/>
        <field name="usd_cost" attrs="{'invisible' :[('simulation_currency', '!=', False)]}"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

The value of the field `usd_cost` becomes invisible but it still shows the column `usd_cost`

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. You can only hide the column permanently like this:

```xml
<field name="bom_line_ids" widget="one2many_list">
    <tree string="Components" editable="bottom" > 
        <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
        <field name="usd_cost" invisible="1" />
    </tree>
</field>
```

Or you can hide the content of the column in some fields as you have done

Answer (score 1):

The Attribute attrs doesnt work for onetomany fields,it could only hide the data in column.But this could work if you replace the onetomany field based on condition.Create a similar onetomany field and in its tree view just avoid the field you want to hide.